# Using virtual memory on Compute Engine with Docker

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I currently have a docker container running on a compute engine that is running out of memory, and now I have used the maximum memory on a machine (128GB). Is there a way to get this setup to use virtual memory so I can just increase the disk space?

Comment: Do you mean allocate swap space? I strongly do not recommend allowing a system to swap memory to disk on systems with virtualized storage. Storage is connected to your VM via the network. You might quickly get into a thrashing situation where the system's performance falls quickly and in some cases does not recover. Google Cloud offers VMs with over 3 TB of memory. A better option is to select a memory-optimized instance size with sufficient physical memory. If you mean enable Docker **--memory-swap**, the same advice applies.

Comment: what application uses 128gb of ram? You sure you dont have memory leaks?